# type inference: df.append() vs df.loc[]

Tags: python, pandas

Let's create an empty DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['member', 'total'])
```

If we add data to `df` with `df.append()`:

```
df = df.append({'member': 'some_string', 'total': pd.Timedelta(...)}, ignore_index=True)
```

we will automatically get object dtype for the `member` column and timedelta64[ns] dtype for the `total` column.

Now let's specify an index during DataFrame creation and add our data with `df.loc[]` instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=some_index, columns=['member', 'total'])

df.loc[index_label] = {'member': 'some_string', 'total': pd.Timedelta(...)}
```

Unfortunately, in this case, we will see object dtype for the `total` column. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.append` creates an entirely new DataFrame, so it can recalculate the best type for all columns.  `df.loc` modifies the existing DataFrame, so it doesn't do that.  (It will only change the types if it needs to make them *less* specific, for instance by converting to object dtype if you insert a string into a numeric column.)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!